# Issue uploading iOS app to the client's developer account after deleting the app from my personal app store connect account

Tags: ios, app-store, app-store-connect

I developed my iOS app and uploaded it on my own developer account now I need to upload the same id with the same bundle ID on the client's developer account. I am trying to add a new APP ID to prepare for App Store submission and got the following error under the bundle ID I provided. "An App ID with Identifier 'pk.ABC.com' is not available. Please enter a different string." I have used this bundle id "pk.upaisa.com" in my other project from a different account and uploaded it onto the testflight. I have tried deleting the ID form identifiers from my other account but it says "The App ID '38J4FHHARX.pk.ABC.com' appears to be in use by the App Store, so it can not be removed at this time.". I have tried deleting the project from app store connect from my second account but the issue still persists. Is there any way I can delete the App Id from my own account and can use it on my client's account?

Comment: Pick a new bundle id. That one is now gone. You should always work in the clients account if you are working on their app. Or use a personal bundle id while working in your account.  By convention your bundle id should be `com.abc.pk` anyway

Comment: I was using a personal bundle id but the client purchased the iXguard license from their bundle id so I had to use their bundle id. I heard you could use the same bundle id for different projects after deleting it from the previous app, but I am not able to do this now.

Comment: If the app has been released you can transfer the app in App Store connect, but as the app has not been released I don't think that there  is anything you can do yourself. You will probably need to raise a support request with Apple